# How to model `break` or `early return` operator in RxJS

Tags: rxjs

What is the most idiomatic way to do this `break` operator?

```js
const source$ = new Subject<string | number>()

source$.pipe(
  break((x: string | number): x is string => typeof x === "string"),
  map(x => x + 1), // x should be inferred as of `number` type.
  map(x => x * 2)
).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));


source$.next("this should bypass") // prints "this should bypass"
source$.next(10) // prints 22
```

I don't want to introduce any "nesting" of operators as I would if I use `switchMap` or something like that.

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right the problem, `filter` should be your friend in this case.

However the type can not be inferred unless you force it to be a number (`(x: string | number): x is number`).

Here the code and a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bsbveb?file=index.ts)

```
source$.pipe(
  filter((x: string | number): x is number => typeof x !== "string"),
  map(x => x + 1), // x should be inferred as of `number` type.
  map(x => x * 2)
).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out inputs that don't match:

```
source$.pipe(
  filter((x: string | number): x is number => typeof x !== "string"),
  map(x => x + 1), // x should be inferred as of `number` type.
  map(x => x * 2)
).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

If you want the observer to stop emitting:

```
source$.pipe(
  takeUntil((x: string | number): x is string => typeof x === "string"),
  map(x => x + 1), // x should be inferred as of `number` type.
  map(x => x * 2)
).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```